# Receiving data on a channel with a blocking default

Tags: go

I have a function which uses a goroutine  to read data from network. This go routine has 2 selects

1. Outer select, with a timer,  to restart reading if the reader fails
2. Inner select that actually reads the data
   And all of this is wrapped in a waitGroup

```
stop := make(chan struct{})
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(1)

go func((){
defer wg.Done()
        ticker := time.NewTicker(restartDuration)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for {
            listener, err := net.ListenUDP()
             if err != nil {
                return err)
            }

          L: // Labelled for loop 

                for {
                    select {
                    case <-stop:
                        return
                    default:
                        n, _, err := listener.ReadFrom(inboundRTPPacket)
                        if err != nil {
                            break L
                        }

                    }
                }
                if err = listener.Close(); err != nil {
                    logrus.Warn("Could not close udp listener")
                }


            select {
            case <-stop:
                return
            case <-ticker.C:
            }
        }
}()
```

A `close(stop)` call is received and acted upon by the outer select if the inner select is removed but does not work with the the inner select.

I am not sure what am I missing here,

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/#PacketConn `// ReadFrom can be made to time out and return an error after a
    // fixed time limit; see SetDeadline and SetReadDeadline.
    ReadFrom(p []byte) (n int, addr Addr, err error)`

Comment: @mh-cbon, I have removed some code for readability, the issue isn't with `ReadFrom`. Thanks for the read though

Comment: you are not reacting to any non-nil error from `listener, err := net.ListenUDP()`

Comment: Edited post to show what I am doing in the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is read-blocking here:

```
n, _, err := listener.ReadFrom(inboundRTPPacket)
```

Even if `close(stop)` is performed later - it will not unblock the code above - because `net.Listener` is not aware of your cancelation mechanism.

[context.Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) is designed for this specific purpose - pass in a `context` to any potentially blocking call. If the call blocks and the `context` is canceled, then the call will unblock.

`io.Reader`'s read operations do not come with context support. It's a very difficult problem:

- Mat Ryer's [blog](https://pace.dev/blog/2020/02/03/context-aware-ioreader-for-golang-by-mat-ryer.html)
- [Cap’n Proto](https://medium.com/@zombiezen/canceling-i-o-in-go-capn-proto-5ae8c09c5b29)

A quick & dirty solution for you, for demonstration purposes:

```
// watches for cancelation:
go func() {
    <-stop
    listener.Close()
}()

// ...

// this will unblock upon `close(stop)` with an error
// as the connection is closed
n, _, err := listener.ReadFrom(inboundRTPPacket)
```

**Note:** you must `close(stop)` after each connection-handler to avoid a goroutine leak.

---

Since you are using a `*net.UDPConn`, a more robust technique would be to leverage the `SetReadDeadline` method to cancel blocked read calls e.g.

```
go func() {

    <-stop // watch for cancelations

    var err error

    // ensure 'listener' has the `SetReadDeadline` method
    // (which *net.UDPConn does)
    if rd, ok := listener.(interface {
        SetReadDeadline(time.Time) error
    }); ok {
        err = rd.SetReadDeadline(time.Now()) // unblock any blocked reads

    } else {
        err = listener.Close() // no deadline method, so default to just closing
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}()
```

again be sure to `close(stop)` to avoid goroutine leaks.